# Angular 4 enable service worker in web application

Tags: angular, service-worker

I am new in angular 4 . I am developing application using angular 4. I need to enable the offline capabilities using service worker.

```
npm i @angular/service-worker --S
```

I tried with above package but its not working i don't know what are the configuration need to make for this service worker. Any one please help me!!

I used the angular service worker i am getting following error in my console.

ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module `C:/projectfolder/node_modules/@angular/service-worker/service-worker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/projectfolder/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/projectfolder/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in C:/projectfolder/src/app/app.module.ts`

Why this error?

Comment: Take a look on this article: https://medium.com/@webmaxru/a-new-angular-service-worker-creating-automatic-progressive-web-apps-part-1-theory-37d7d7647cc7

Comment: @MartinNuc i tried from above link but i am getting above error in my console. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @MartinNuc still i am confused . I am not getting any clear idea about this config

Answer (score 1):

When researching which service worker library to use (as of October 2017), I saw complaints of poor documentation and few examples for all of the big players, which appear to be,

- [@angular/service-worker](https://coryrylan.com/blog/fast-offline-angular-apps-with-service-workers)
- [sw-precache](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sw-precache/#0)
- [Workbox](https://workboxjs.org/#get-started)

I opted for Workbox because it's billed as the sw-precache sucessor (which by all reports actually worked and is in use) and offered better docs than @angular/service-worker which still appears to be in its infancy.

**To create a service worker using Workbox**, using workbox-cli (the simplest approach):

```
npm install --save-dev workbox-cli --global
(Accept the defaults and write sw.js to the dist folder)
```

Then edit **main.ts** until it looks something like this:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .then(() => {
    registerServiceWorker('sw');
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

  function registerServiceWorker(swName: string) {
    if (environment.production) {
      if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker
          .register(`/${swName}.js`)
          .then(reg => {
            console.log('[App] Successful service worker registration', reg);
          })
          .catch(err =>
            console.error('[App] Service worker registration failed', err)
          );
      } else {
        console.error('[App] Service Worker API is not supported in current browser');
      }
    }
  }
```

Build your app for production

```
ng build --prod && workbox-cli generate:sw
```

Install the [Chrome Web Server](https://github.com/kzahel/web-server-chrome) extension from the Chrome web store and point it at your dist folder.  Then access it using the address provided by Chrome Web Server.  Open the Console (F12) before loading your app and you should see a message in the console confirming that the service worker was registered.

Answer (score 0):

**I think you can't use service workers with angular 4, you need to upgrade to angular 5**.

If you check the [API list for angular 4](https://v4.angular.io/api) you will notice that there are no service workers but if you check the [API list for angular 5](https://v5.angular.io/api) you will see that it is added there that's why I think that in order to use service workers in angular, *you must upgrade to angular 5*.

Also it is stated in [Angular Service Worker Into](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-intro) that service workers starts with angular 5.